# SQL Server json truncated (even when using NVARCHAR(max) )

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

```
DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(max);

SET @result = (SELECT * FROM table
               FOR JSON AUTO, ROOT('Data'))

SELECT @result;
```

This returns a json string of ~43000 characters, with some results truncated.

```
SET @result = (SELECT * FROM table
               FOR JSON AUTO, ROOT('Data'))
```

This returns a json string of ~2000 characters. Is there any way to prevent any truncation? Even when dealing with some bigdata and the string is millions and millions of characters?

Comment: can you add some test data to take a look, and both queries looks the same, there should be no difference

Comment: @Surendra well, neither query works, one just returns more data, the data is identical.    So for example, the second query returns 2000~ characters, and those first ~2000 characters are identical to the first ~2000 characters  of the first query.  However, even the first query gets heavily truncated.  I am just trying to trying to return a json string with all data for the table, even if its insanely massive.

Comment: @Surendra I would prefer to not give test data, as I would have to spend time sanitizing all of it and don't see how that would be useful, but I can if need be

Comment: When you say truncating, do you mean that the entire string is not getting returned in your SSMS window?

Comment: @dfundako Correct, it just gets cutoff mid column.  I have tried using SSMS, querying via dotnet and node, all have the same result.  So it's not a SSMS issue.

Comment: @jayjay93 Try going to Tools, Options, Query Results, SQL Server, Results to Grid, and set Non-XML data to the max amount (I think 65535)

Comment: Have you tried running `SELECT DATALENGTH(@result);` and see what you get? I'm pretty sure this is just a display problem in SSMS - the data itself inside the variable should be fine

Answer (score 16):

I didn't find and 'official' answer, but it seems that this is an error with the new 'FOR JSON' statement which is splitting the result in lines 2033 characters long.
As recommended [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/408) the best option so far is to iterate through the results concatenating the returned rows:

```
string result = "";
while (reader.Read())
{
    result += Convert.ToString(reader[0]);                        
}
```

BTW, it seems that the latest versions of SSMS are already applying some kind of workaround like this to present the result in a single row.

Comment: tbh, to concat a string like that is very resource hungry. Better to use a StringBuilder like it is specified in the documentation.

Answer (score 16):

The easiest workaround to avoid the truncation is to wrap the query in another select:

```
select (
     <your query> FOR JSON PATH [or FOR JSON AUTO]
) as json
```

Comment: This works perfectly in SSMS v18.3. Needs more up votes! Does anyone know if truncation still occurs in later versions of SSMS?

Comment: Works great and minimal extra syntax. I have used similar workaround for XML output with CDATA, and here we too wrap the query in another query to have output that is not truncated.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to get the full, non-truncated string by using `print` instead of `select` in SQL Server 2017 (version 14.0.2027):

```
DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(max);

SET @result = (SELECT * FROM table
           FOR JSON AUTO, ROOT('Data'))

PRINT @result;
```

Another option would be to download and use [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download) which I think is a multi-platform re-write of SSMS (similar to how Visual Studio was re-written as VS Code). It seems to spit out the entire, non-truncated json string as expected out of the box!

Comment: Note: PRINT don't return nothing if you need to use in your system. SELECT will do that.

Comment: `SELECT (SELECT ... FOR JSON AUTO)` will do exactly the same as this

Comment: I'm still getting truncating with Azure Data Studio

Comment: I still get truncation, SSMS 18.1, SQL Server 2019.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old thread but I have had success with this issue by sending the result to an XML variable. The advantage of using an XML variable is that the size is not stated as character length but by size of the string in memory, which can be changed in the options. Therefore Brad C's response would now look like...

```
DECLARE @result XML
SET @result = (SELECT * FROM table
FOR JSON AUTO, ROOT('Data'))
SELECT @result

or...

PRINT @result;
```

Comment: Tried this, but get a conversion error "Implicit conversion from data type xml to nvarchar is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query."

Answer (score 6):

This will also work if you insert into a temp table - not presenting does not apply the truncate of SSMS.
Might be usefull if you need to calculate several values.

```
declare @json table (j nvarchar(max));
insert into @json select * from(select* from Table where Criteria1 for json auto)a(j)
insert into @json select * from(select* from Table where Criteria2 for json auto)a(j)
select * from @json
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This didn't do it for me in SSMSC v18.12.1. Same truncation.

Comment: Just downloaded and installed bother latest SSMSC 19.0.202 and Azure data stud and json is truncated with both.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the answer to JSON truncation:

SQL *divides the JSON result into chunks* 2k in size (at least my SQL 2016 installation does), one chunk in the first column of each row in the result set.  To get the entire result, your client code has to loop through the result set and concatenate the first column of each record.  When you've gotten to the end of the rows, voila, your entire JSON result is retrieved, uncut.

When I first encountered the truncation problem I was baffled, and wrote off **FOR JSON** for several years as an unserious feature suited only to the smallest of datasets.  I learned that I need to read the entire recordset only from the **FOR XML** documentation, and never actually saw it mentioned in the **FOR JSON** docs.

Comment: Ok sure...how would you go about reading the entire recordset inside something like SSMS? Never heard of that...

Answer (score 3):

We've seen similar issues in SSMS, without using a variable SSMS truncates at 2033.

With a variable the query actually works OK when you use an nvarcahr(max) variable, but it truncates the output in the query results view at 43697.

A possible solution I've tested is outputting Query results to a file, using BCP:

`bcp  "DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(max); SET @result = (SELECT * FROM table FOR JSON AUTO, ROOT('Data')); SELECT @result as Result;" queryout "D:\tmp\exportOutput.txt" -S SQL_SERVER_NAME -T -w`

[See BCP docs for specifying server name\instance and authentication options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017#S)

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to determine exactly what the problem you're having without posting the data, but I had a similar problem when I was attempting to export a query in JSON format. The solution that worked for me was to go to Query/Query Options/Results/Text/Set "Maximum number of characters displayed in each column:" to 8192 (max value AFAIK).

This probably won't help much with your first query, but that potentially could be broken into smaller queries and executed successfully. I would anticipate that you could effectively run your second query after changing that setting.

Answer (score 1):

Try Visual Studio Code with Microsoft SQL extension. I got 6800 characters of JSON without truncation. It seems SSMS truncates results.

Comment: You can also use Azure Data Studio and it won't truncate the results.

Answer (score 0):

If your datalength is less than 65535 then you should use the suggestion of [@dfundako](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087037/sql-server-json-truncated-even-when-using-nvarcharmax#comment89164591_51087037) who commented in the first post:

> Try going to Tools, Options, Query Results, SQL Server, Results to Grid, and set Non-XML data to the max amount (I think 65535)

In my case the datalength was 21k characters so after exporting to grid I copied the value and it was fine, not truncated. Still it doesn't solve the the issue for those with bigger amount of data.

Comment: In SSMSC the max appears to be 2097152 which finally fixed it for me.