# Long json strings truncated when returned via .net API

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, string

I have a SQL Server Stored Proc that returns json using FOR JSON. If I call the proc in SQL it returns correctly and the output can be validated with something like jsonlint. However, the proc is called from a .net API layer, and when the json is long-ish, it seems to truncate the string it gets from the proc and thus has invalid json. If I reduce the amount of data returned, I get a valid json string through the API, but if it goes over a certain number of characters, it's truncated.

This result from the proc is fine:

```
{"APIResult":[{"ID":200,"Status_Message":"Success","User_Message":"Success","OperatingCountries":[{"Country_Name":"Mexico","ISO_Alpha2":"MX","ISO_Alpha3":"MEX","UN_Code":"484","Legal_Age":18,"Default_Language":"es"},{"Country_Name":"United States of America","ISO_Alpha2":"US","ISO_Alpha3":"USA","UN_Code":"840","Legal_Age":21,"Default_Language":"en-us"}]}]}
```

But this result, is not:

```
{"APIResult":[{"ID":200,"Status_Message":"Success","User_Message":"Success","OperatingCountries":[{"Country_Name":"Afghanistan","ISO_Alpha2":"AF","ISO_Alpha3":"AFG","UN_Code":"004","Legal_Age":18,"Default_Language":"en-gb"},{"Country_Name":"Angola","ISO_Alpha2":"AO","ISO_Alpha3":"AGO","UN_Code":"024","Legal_Age":18,"Default_Language":"en-gb"},{"Country_Name":"Albania","ISO_Alpha2":"AL","ISO_Alpha3":"ALB","UN_Code":"008","Legal_Age":18,"Default_Language":"en-gb"},{"Country_Name":"Andorra","ISO_Alpha2":"AD","ISO_Alpha3":"AND","UN_Code":"020","Legal_Age":18,"Default_Language":"en-gb"},{"Country_Name":"Argentina","ISO_Alpha2":"AR","ISO_Alpha3":"ARG","UN_Code":"032","Legal_Age":18,"Default_Language":"es"},{"Country_Name":"Armenia","ISO_Alpha2":"AM","ISO_Alpha3":"ARM","UN_Code":"051","Legal_Age":18,"Default_Language":"en-gb"},{"Country_Name":"American Samoa","ISO_Alpha2":"AS","ISO_Alpha3":"ASM","UN_Code":"016","Legal_Age":18,"Default_Language":"en-gb"},{"Country_Name":"Antarctica","ISO_Alpha2":"AQ","ISO_Alpha3":"ATA","UN_Code":"010","Legal_Age":18,"Default_Language":"en-gb"},{"Country_Name":"Antigua and Barbuda","ISO_Alpha2":"AG","ISO_Alpha3":"ATG","UN_Code":"028","Legal_Age":18,"Default_Language":"en-gb"},{"Country_Name":"Australia","ISO_Alpha2":"AU","ISO_Alpha3":"AUS","UN_Code":"036","Legal_Age":18,"Default_Language":"en-gb"},{"Country_Name":"Austria","ISO_Alpha2":"AT","ISO_Alpha3":"AUT","UN_Code":"040","Legal_Age":18,"Default_Language":"en-gb"},{"Country_Name":"Azerbaijan","ISO_Alpha2":"AZ","ISO_Alpha3":"AZE","UN_Code":"031","Legal_Age":18,"Default_Language":"en-gb"},{"Country_Name":"Belgium","ISO_Alpha2":"BE","ISO_Alpha3":"BEL","UN_Code":"056","Legal_Age":18,"Default_Language":"en-gb"},{"Country_Name":"Bangladesh","ISO_Alpha2":"BD","ISO_Alpha3":"BGD","UN_Code":"050","Legal_Age":18,"Default_Language":"en-gb"},{"Country_Name":"Bahrain","ISO_Alpha2":"BH","ISO_Alpha3":"BHR","UN_Code":"048","Legal_Age":18,"Default_Language":"en-gb"},{"Country_Name":"Bahamas","ISO_Alpha2":"BS","ISO_Alpha3":"BHS","UN_Code":"044","Legal_Age":18,"Default_Language":"en-gb"},{"Country_Name":"Bosnia and Herzegovina","ISO_Alpha2":"BA","ISO_Alpha3":"BIH","UN_Code":"070","Legal_Age":18,"Default_Language":"en-gb"},{"Country_Name":"Bermuda","ISO_Alpha2":"BM","ISO_Alpha3":"BMU","UN_Code":"060","Legal_Age":18,"Default_Language":"en-gb"},{"Country_Name":"Bolivia","ISO_Alpha2":"BO","ISO_Alpha3":"BOL","UN_Code":"068","Legal_Age":18,"Default_Language":"en-gb"},{"Country_Name":"Barbados","ISO_Alpha2":"BB","ISO_Alpha3":"BRB","UN_Code":"052","Legal_Age":18,"Default_Language":"en-gb"},{"Country_Name":"Bhutan","ISO_Alpha2":"BT","ISO_Alpha3":"BTN","UN_Code":"064","Legal_Age":18,"Default_Language":"en-gb"},{"Country_Name":"Bouvet Island","ISO_Alpha2":"BV","ISO_Alpha3":"BVT","UN_Code":"074","Legal_Age":18,"Default_Language":"en-gb"},{"Country_Name":"Botswana","ISO_Alpha2":"BW","ISO_Alpha3":"BWA","UN_Code":"072","Legal_Age":18,"Default_Language":"en-gb"},{"Country_Name":"Algeria","ISO_Alpha2":"DZ","ISO_Alpha3":"DZA","UN_Code":"012","Legal_Age":18,"Default_Language":"en-gb"},{"Country_Name":"Mexico","ISO_Alpha2":"MX","ISO_Alpha3":"MEX","UN_Code":"484","Legal_Age":18,"Default_Language":"es"},{"Country_Name":"United States of  America","ISO_Alpha2":"US","ISO_Alpha3":"USA","UN_Code":"840","Legal_Age":21,"Default_Language":"en-us"}]}]}
```

This is the code in the API project:

```
cmd2 = new SqlCommand("GetOperatingCountries");
cmd2.Connection = conn2;
cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd2.CommandTimeout = 1000;

SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "DefaultLanguage";
if (DefaultLanguage.ToUpper() == "NULL")
{ param.Value = DBNull.Value; }
else { param.Value = DefaultLanguage; }
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
param.IsNullable = true;
cmd2.Parameters.Add(param);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
da.Fill(ds);
message = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();

var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StringContent(message, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
return ResponseMessage(response);
```

The first example produces nice json in postman, but the second just returns the unformatted truncated string.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: Are they, by any chance, being truncated at 4,000 or 8,000 characters?

Comment: There is no truncated or invalid JSON in your second example. Do you mean you expect more country records to be returned?

Comment: What is your `maxJsonLength` in your web.config?

Comment: It looks like you are getting both en-gb and en-us.  So make sure in your request you specify en-us.  You can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to check the request to make sure you are sending the country language in the request.

Comment: Why you are using Rows[0][0]?

Comment: This one looks like a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087037/sql-server-json-truncated-even-when-using-nvarcharmax.

Comment: Codecaster, the second example is what should be returned via the API. It's what is returned by the stored proc, but postman shows that it truncates this.

Comment: Just to be sure, when you debug, does `message` contains the full string result or is it truncated?

Comment: Lamu, it's smaller than that. it seems to be at different points. Last time it truncated at around 2033 chars.
kibik, no, the text viewer is showing it as having been truncated

Comment: In that case, it is not a web api issue. Have you followed my answer? you need to concat *all* returned rows. not just the first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The returned JSON might be returned in multiple rows for lengthy results.

See [Format Query Results as JSON with FOR JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) (section "*Output of the FOR JSON clause*") and [Use FOR JSON output in a C# client app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/use-for-json-output-in-sql-server-and-in-client-apps-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#use-for-json-output-in-a-c-client-app)

```
var queryWithForJson = "SELECT ... FOR JSON";
var conn = new SqlConnection("<connection string>");
var cmd = new SqlCommand(queryWithForJson, conn);
conn.Open();
var jsonResult = new StringBuilder();
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (!reader.HasRows)
{
    jsonResult.Append("[]");
}
else
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        jsonResult.Append(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. This works. I have to refactor all the controllers to work with this, but it does provide the right result, thanks kobik

Answer (score 0):

Try to set max request Lnegth or maxAllowedContentLength

```
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="65536" />

<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Comment: Where in the web.config do these lines go? Can you give me a pointer?